# How to determine the values for the PrefixList attribute of the InclusiveNamespaces element

Tags: c#, soap, ws-security, xml-signature

When signing a `SOAP` request, how should I determine what values need to be listed in the `PrefixList` attribute of the `InclusiveNamespaces` element?

I'm trying to make sure that what I have set mine to is correct, but have very little to base this off of.

I hope this is a simple question, but please let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Would like to know the answer as well.

Comment: @Simas.B I never got resolution specifically for this generalized question, however, for the project I was working on I had a sample of the XML.  In that sample were the values I needed to implement, and IIRC, I was simply not implementing it correctly in my application.  Once I implemented it correctly, I didn't have a problem.